# What will be the speed of water at any point below tank bottom and above the top most tap when one or the other tap is open

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

[image]

Hi All,

I need your help in figuring a simple problem.

I want to figure out if there will be any speed difference just bellow the water tank If I open tap A or tap B.

I want to measure the speed of the water at any point below tank bottom and above tap A in both scenarios.

Scenario 1: tap A is open and tap B is closed

Scenario 2: tap B is open and tap A is closed

And if there is a speed difference. Then what is the concept behind it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about Torricelli's law?

Comment: Hi Satyanarayan and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).